# can we mix struts and html tag in single page

Tags: html, struts2

i have jsp file in which most of tha struts tag now for some field i have to use simple html tag
but when i put html tag the format of page is chaged.
if i use only struts tag then each strut tag are written in new row so. how can i show two different struts tag in single row.

Answer (score 1):

You *can use* normal HTML tags along with Struts tags in a JSP. Struts isn't strict in that way. Regarding the error that you get, it would be much better if you could post the code you use and describe in detail the error that you get.

Note that I haven't really worked in Struts2 - only in Struts 1, but I assume you should still be able to mix normal HTML tags with Struts tags in Struts2 too...

Comment: i have solve that problem by putting theme=simple in form tag.
so that struts can not add it own format.and then simple write string directly as html. beacause label is not working when we use theme=simple.